# User Interface Language for Browsers/Desktops/Android

Tags: user-interface

I'm looking for a user interface language to create an application that can be easily ported to run as a cross-browser web application, desktop application, and Android application. Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have a *very* hard time writing the same UIs for mobile and desktop; your best shot is probably a combination of [Titanium Desktop](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/) and [Mobile](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go for Flash. Really and too easy to port cross-browser and OSes and be supported by a vast majority of Android devices, especially tablets.

If you don't plan to port it to iOS (iPhone, iPad), you should be fine with Flash.

Maybe there will be different opinions out there....

Comment: I can only disagree, based on the slow-but-inevitable death of Flash.

Comment: You might be right, but there is still a loooooot of developpers out here that still develop for Flash. I think in maybe 10 years it will be outdated